# How can I change a preact signal value from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, signals, preact

```
export const clicked = signal(false);


    const handleClickDay = (date) => {
        const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2,'0')
        const month = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2,'0')
        const year = date.getYear().toString().padStart(2,'0')
        clickedDate.value = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
        console.log(clickedDate.value);
        clicked.value = true;
    }
```

The value gets imported in another component but I want to change the clicked to false from that component

I have tried changing it directly but it shows an error

```
{clicked.value = false}
```

It shows the error
`Cannot update a component (CalendarBase) while rendering a different component (MiniTodo). To locate the bad setState() call inside MiniTodo, follow the stack trace as described`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
    const handleClick = () =>{
            effect(() => clicked.value = false)
        }
```

This code with a button made it so that it doesn't re-render the app to many times

Comment: This doesn't make sense and certainly isn't what you want to do -- every time `clicked` changes values, this effect will run, setting it to be `false`